# What is exact meaning of lexicographically sorted order?

Tags: lexicographic-ordering

I have tried to understand that, for example if an array consist of 2 element say 2 and 11.
the lexicographically order would be 11 , 2 (Since 1st element, It's all digit lie smaller than compare to 2nd element digit)

And in other case, where if we have a list containing two words, {educative, educated}. So to sort this list in lexicographical order.
after comparing these two words letter by letter and sorting these letters alphabetically. As a result, our list will become {educated, educative}. (since we have 2 unmatched character, And 'e' comes before 'i', so word2 comes before word1).

So is this how lexicographically order work in both case?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. With words lexicographic order is what we naturally expect. It's not so for numbers. Lexicographic sorting does not order them the way most people expect, with your example of `2` and `11` being a great illustration.

Comment: The explanation you have is correct.
Lexical word itself means related to words hence lexicographical sort means how the words are sorted in a dictionary.